using ContentBlockById vs directly adding AMPscript in a Code Snippet
I have several emails that use the same AMPscript logic across different email. I'm wondering if there is a significant difference between calling the AMPscript via ContentBlockById in a Code Snippet versus adding the AMPscript directly within the Code Snippet itself.
The main reason I'm considering ContentBlockById is to centralize the AMPscript code so I don't have to update it in multiple places every time there’s a change.
Would it be better to use ContentBlockById for maintainability, or are there performance implications or other considerations that I should be aware of?

I am using ContentBlockByKEY (not ID*) pretty much in every email, heavily.
I have never made a dedicated load test but also have never observed anything negative that would convince me to do one.
The centralization is a good idea in general, as is the use of templates (or  the combination of both).
*Note I would prefer Key as it makes your code much more readable, given you can assign human readable Customer Keys, and probably will use references a lot. Ids are always numeric gibberish, and human readable keys keep a last semblance of user friendliness.
======
Keep in mind for maintainability:

Running Journeys /triggered sends do not accept code changes no matter which way you pick - direct insertion, ContentBlockByKey, ContentBlockByID, all the same.
(ContentBlockByID is the same as using Reference Content btw).

In active Journeys / Triggered Sends, you still have to refresh the affected email manually (which is the same as pause / publish changes / restart) for all scenarios.
A downside: With references, you will have no real idea which Journey / TS has or has not been updated, as you would be able to see with plain code being in each email.
To be honest I would not let that stop me - this feature, well intentioned as it might be, is anyway a huge time sink for rolling out changes at scale.
For scale, I would anyway build infrastructure for change logging and quicker maintenance (== refreshing the triggered sends via API).
For reference; The only way that is NOT picked up as a code change by this logic is if the result of a lookup() function changes. Makes sense, as the actual code of the lookup is unchanged.

In templates, a change in a ContentBlockByKey or ContentBlockByID reference does NOT prompt the "template changed" warning, as opposed to direct insertion. Once more: well-intentioned, the warning might be helpful in some cases. However at scale, I think this is an argument FOR using references.

